# transaction status paypal adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I do not understand this IPN values:

```
status=COMPLETED
transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn=Pending
transaction[0].status=Pending
```

I'm using adaptive payments, but I don't know why status is allways COMPLETED and transaction[0].status is allways Pending!!!!

I'm using sandbox, but I don't understand why the transactions are allways pending, I don't know when to enable the buyer to download the contents that he payed...

And there is no official documentation on the web...

Answer (score 0):

The status of the transaction can be Pending in 'delayed chained' payments or if the receiver does not have a PayPal account. Can you post the whole payload? I can see only a part of it. Is this a chained payment you are trying? Is the receiver primary or secondary?

Comment: Thank you, now I solved the problem! It was a transaction from a single sender to a single receiver but the receiver needed to convert the currency or create a new balance in another currency, so the status was COMPLETED (enable to download the contents) and the transaction Pending until the receiver decided what to do.